# Cakephp 4.0 Authentication Example

Tags: authentication, cakephp-4.x

I tried cakephp 4.0 authentication tutorial from: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html. But there is problem. On sql create there is only username and no email, but on source code email and password are used to authenticate. I tried to change all email on source code to username. Add user works fine, but when I tried user login on /users/login it shows "invalid username or password" error.

Please help me.

Comment: For starters, check what data and possible errors the result object holds, make sure you have debug mode enabled (see `config/app.php` and/or `config/app_local.php`), and then in your login action before the `$this->Flash->error();` call, do `debug($result->getData());` and `debug($result->getErrors());`, and add the result to your question. Also check your database what exactly the data looks like that was inserted for your user, ie is the username correct, and is the password being stored as a hash (add those details to your question too please)?

Comment: If you've made changes to the users table recently, make sure that the [schema cache has been cleared](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/console-commands/schema-cache.html) since then.

Comment: show us your code mate, maybe just maybe you are missing some steps.

show us your content of these code, src/model/entity/user and src/model/table/user